# What's the best way to control a NSTableView's selection using checkboxes?

Tags: cocoa, checkbox, nstableview, nsoutlineview

For some user interfaces it makes sense to have explicit checkboxes to allow users to select the items in a table. What's the best way to accomplish this using cocoa? In other words, how can I link the state of a checkbox in each row to whether or not the row is currently selected?

Answer (score 0):

Tony,

if I  get you correctly, you want to add a leading column to your NSTableView so you can  select the corresponding column(s), separate from the usual selection of the tableView.

What is your datasource of the table view? A core data stuff or an array/dictionary? if you do not want to modify your data model, you could set up a distinct array (mutable), to keep track of the selection. bind it to the checkbox column (you would want to add as first column) and keep the array in sync with the number of items in the general datasource for the table that displays your valuable data.

You could also enhance your data model with a column "selected", make it BOOL and bind it to the checkboxes. This would also allow you to easily save the last selection to you database or file, whatever you are using.

Can you update your question with some more information on your data model?

sya - living.